# how to get my facebook wall with JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm testing a simple code to retrieve the last 5 posts from my personal facebook wall, then add them to the html with my personal css style. But I get only empty data! I'm using Graph API 2.3, on a web page.

I've created an app, called "cambiamentico". So I got the appid 421429864732436 and the secure code. My personal id, istead, is 100000007731737. NB - the app is not yet submitted for review, since it's only a test and doesn't work. Is it a problem?

If I ask, for example, "cocacolait/posts?limit=5", I get the 5 complete posts of that Page, but when I ask "100000007731737/?limit=5" I get only an empty data.

I guess there's some issue with permissions, maybe something called "access token" which I really don't know how to "make"... or find.

Here's the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '421429864732436',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.3'
    });
    testGetPosts();
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testGetPosts(){
    //this work
    FB.api('/cocacolait/posts?limit=5', function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
    //this, my private page (with public posts), doesn't work
    FB.api('/100000007731737/posts?limit=5', function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are fetching your own posts your app doesn't need to go through review.
And as you mentioned you are indeed missing an access token. If you are to fetch your posts from your Facebook wall you will need to make request to graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token = "access_token with read_stream permission"

To get access token go through: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

Comment: yes, I get it, but in [fb login page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3) I see only how to require a login from a user if he's not logged in my app, and ask him permission for using **his** datas. is it possible to give unlimited access to my app only  to **my** account, and show in my web page only my posts to every user?

Comment: Yeah that is possible.

Comment: any hint to go? or a link to someone who already has solved this issue? PS - I read that, to access private posts, you need review.

Comment: No, giving “unlimited” access is _not_ possible. User access tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days – after that, you will have to login again to generate a new one. But you should not expose your own user access token in client-side code that will be accessible to others. If you want to create an app that shows your own posts, then you should use a server-side component to fetch those posts.

Comment: @CBroe ok, thank you. As expected the only solution is to login server side (in my case PHP). I'll give it a shot.